# m8 shows up as porable media player

Tags: htc

I want to pull off my pics and no folders show up.  I tried with the screen on and off, different usb ports.  STill shows up at HTC on m8 with no folders.

Suggestions?
Thanks!
Julie

Comment: My suggestion is to describe more clearly what you're trying to do, what exact steps you took, and what the problem is. As it stands, it's not easy to understand your question at all.

Answer (score -1):

Connect your device to your computer using the USB cable provided. Then make sure you unlock the device before attempting to access folders/files.